# React upgrade issue "Error: Path is not a string"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

This is ONE of the many files with this same error.

```js
// Load dependencies
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Radium from 'radium';
import {Typeahead} from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';

// Load styles
import 'react-bootstrap-typeahead/css/Typeahead.css';

/**
 * Render a Typeahead input that gives autocomplete suggestions.
 */
class YATypeahead extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Typeahead {...this.props} />
    );
  }
}

// Export component, connected to Radium
export default Radium(YATypeahead);
```

```
Module not found: Error: path argument is not a string
 @ ./js/containers/main/main.jsx 51:0-60 689:42-53
 @ ./js/containers/router/router.jsx 57:0-36 115:19-25 116:17-31
 @ ./js/containers/root/root.development.jsx 39:0-42 75:42-50
 @ ./js/containers/root/root.js 8:12-58
 @ ./js/index.js 22:0-42 56:41-45
```

this is the error, I do not know what is wrong I have google what I feel like is endlessly,

and among that these are the rest of said errors that I also have no clue what to do or where to go. Can ANYONE please point me in the right direction of what I have wrong here.

```
ERROR in ./js/index.js 12:0-28
Module not found: Error: path argument is not a string

ERROR in ./js/index.js 14:0-52
Module not found: Error: path argument is not a string

ERROR in ./js/index.js 15:0-48
Module not found: Error: path argument is not a string

ERROR in ./js/index.js 16:0-45
Module not found: Error: path argument is not a string

ERROR in ./js/index.js 17:0-35
Module not found: Error: path argument is not a string

ERROR in ./js/reducers/index.js 5:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:7)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| };
|
> export about from './about';
| export authenticator from './authenticator';
| export classroom from './classroom';
 @ ./js/store/configure-store.development.js 20:0-42 36:60-68
 @ ./js/store/configure-store.js 8:12-69
 @ ./js/index.js 20:0-53 54:12-26
```

I'm going on lunch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research, and some testing.

I've done this with my reducers/index.js file

```js
import {combineReducers} from "redux";

import about from './about';
import authenticator from './authenticator';
import classroom from './classroom';
import feed from './feed';
import location from './location';
import mealPlan from './meal-plan';
import message from './message';
import parent from './parent';
import progress from './progress';
import region from './region';
import settings from './settings';
import staff from './staff';
import student from './student';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    about,
    authenticator,
    classroom,
    feed,
    location,
    mealPlan,
    message,
    parent,
    progress,
    region,
    settings,
    staff,
    student
});

export default rootReducer;
```

and this seems to get be past the error, however I am unsure if this is a proper fix or not as application isn't serving me any webpages and has other console errors now.

If there is a better or more proper solution to what is happening, please comment.